# How to programatically lock BLACKBERRY device(6.0)?

Tags: blackberry

how to lock blackberry device 6.0 pro-grammatically?
there is an API called 
ApplicationManger.locksystem(true)
but its diprecated in 6.0

Answer (score 1):

According to the [BlackBerry OS 7.1 API documentation](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/7.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/system/ApplicationManager.html#lockSystem%28boolean%29) the parameter *force* is depricated, the API call should still be valid. Have you tried it?

Comment: Hi, ApplicationManger.locksystem(true) will work only upto OS 4.7, it seems. On all other OS, it'll not work. It doesn't throw any error; but it won't work. 

Does anybody has answer for this ?
Thanks in advance...!!!