# How to lock Blackberry device from inside the application?

Tags: blackberry

As per the BB documentation, we have ApplicationManger.locksystem(true); but it's deprecated since OS 4.7. When I tried this, it doesn't throw any error, but it is not working.

Is there any way we can lock the BB device with OS version 5.0 and later programmatically ?
this qn here : [How to programatically lock BLACKBERRY device(6.0)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10682153/how-to-programatically-lock-blackberry-device6-0) is the same. But nobody has answered it yet; so Im posting it again.
 Thanks in advance.

Comment: i think this will help you MemoryCleanerListener.EVENT_DEVICE_LOCK

Comment: I can see the device locked indicator event. But, Is there any for locking the device ?

Comment: You can try to inject a lock key press using `EventInjector` class.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.... But how can we get the event for lock key press ?