# Is there any class on BlackBerry similar to DevicePolicyManager on Android?

Tags: android, blackberry, java-me, applicationmanager

I have an Android application that uses [DevicePolicyManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager.html). In that application, I can call some methods to lock phone, reset password, ...

Now, I'm cloning this application on BlackBerry. I tried to use the `ApplicationManager` class and call `lockSystem(true)`. But the phone is not locked, only the keyboard is locked and when pressing the **"End Call"** key, the keyboard is unlocked again.

Please tell me if there is any class on BlackBerry that is similar to `DevicePolicyManager` on Android.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, no.

It looks like [the ApplicationManager#lockSystem(true) call has been deprecated for a while now](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10683935/119114).

The BlackBerry APIs also [don't provide a way to reset the password](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/How-to-set-password-in-device-programmatically/td-p/1726377), although an administrator can do this with BES.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
Could you please explain more about reset the password with BES?

Comment: @phuc_tran, that's not really a *programming* question, and sadly, I'm just a programmer :).  However, it looks like [this page might have the information you need](http://btsc.webapps.blackberry.com/btsc/viewdocument.do;jsessionid=7FD1CC029F57BCC8D2B2ED50C5DDBE64?externalId=KB10711&sliceId=2&cmd=displayKC&docType=kc&noCount=true&ViewedDocsListHelper=com.kanisa.apps.common.BaseViewedDocsListHelperImpl).  I'm not sure it helps you, though, if you want to build an **app** that resets passwords.

Comment: I just read BB10 Library Support : http://developer.blackberry.com/native/reference/bb10/library_support_at_a_glance_reference.html
And I can't find any API for locking phone.
Do you know any API that can do locking phone or password processing(reset, clear,...)?

Comment: @phuc_tran, BlackBerry 10 is a **completely** different system.  I don't develop for BB10.  If you have a question about that, please just post a new question, and remember to use the `blackberry-10` tag.  Thanks.